# Json check if certain element has been received

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, boolean

I have an ajax call to one of my servlets that does some database manipulation. The question I am asking is, is there and easy way to see if I receive a certain element in my json. For example, I am receiving back a { message: "Some data message" } but if there is an error, I want to send back {error: "my error message"}. Is there a simple way to see if there was an error sent?
The logic I am thinking of is like this (this does not work)

```
$.post( "database.json", { id: id, info: info})
  .done(function( data ) {
      if(data.error){
          alert(data.error);
      } else {
          alert(data.message);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this with

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    alert(data.error);
} else {
    alert(data.message);
}
```